# Function as parameter with params arg

Tags: c#

I have a function with this signature:

```
public static async Task LoadAsync<T>(T model, Func<T, PropertyInfo, Task> comparer, params string[] includes) where T: class
```

which I invoke like this:

```
await EagerLoader.LoadAsync(model, SetPropertyValue, includes);
```

The **SetPropertyValue** is the function that I pass to **LoadAsync**. It's signature is like this:

```
private async Task SetPropertyValue(Account model, PropertyInfo property)
```

What I would like to do is change that signature to this:

```
private async Task SetPropertyValue(Account model, PropertyInfo property, params string[] includes)
```

How do I represent that in my **LoadAsync** signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` qualifier is not part of the type. At run-time, its presence is represented as an attribute [`[ParamArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the definition of your method's parameter.

If you change the type to

```
Func<T, PropertyInfo, string[], Task>
```

you would be able to pass both

```
Task SetPropertyValue(Account model, PropertyInfo property, params string[] includes)
```

and

```
Task SetPropertyValue(Account model, PropertyInfo property, string[] includes)
```

(i.e. with and without `params`). Since `params` is not part of the parameter type, `string[]` cannot be classified as `params` in the type arguments of the `Func` generic delegate.

This should work fine in your use case, because your `LoadAsync` will not need to invoke the `comparer` delegate using the variable-argument syntax, i.e. `LoadAsync` would be passing the whole array, rather than a variable-length list of `string`s that the compiler must combine into an array.